# confirming a dropdownlist value has been selected before button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I need to write jQuery code that will allow me to confirm that a value has been selected in a dropdownlist when a button is clicked. If the value has not been selected in the dropdownlist then pop an alert to that matter.

I have tried a couple things but they have not worked so far.
I wrote a jQuery function:

```
        function CheckCylinder() {
        if ($('#comboCylinders').value != "None") {
            alert('You must first select a cylinder.');
        }
    }
```

that I was calling from the asp button OnClientClick:

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonModCylinder" runat ="server" Text="Modify Cylinder" 
        Width= "384px" Height= "102px" CssClass="cssCommandButton "
style = "position : absolute; top:104px; Left : 189px" OnClientClick="CheckCylinder()" />
```

That does not seem to work...
Please let me know what I need to look at. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to either use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) with jQuery, or use a native element with `value`

```
function CheckCylinder() {
    if (document.getElementById('comboCylinders').value == "None") {
        alert('You must first select a cylinder.');
    }
}
```

assuming something like

```
<select id="comboCylinders">
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <option value="cylinder 1">cylinder 1</option>
    <option value="cylinder 2">cylinder 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, the dropdownlist options are like that.

Comment: @Ryan - Then the answer should work, as long as you got the ASP part rigth and the click event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckCylinder()
{
    if(!$("#comboCylinders").is(":checked")) // Checkboxes-radio
    {
    // or
    if(!$("#comboCylinders").is(":selected")) // Select
    {
    // or
    if($("#comboCylinders").val() == "") // Textinput
    {
```